# Magento 1.9 addAttributeToFilter not filtering result

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, product-collection

I have the following code, where I want it to retrieve a list of simple products from the table **sales_flat_order_items**

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('product_type', array('eq'=>'simple'))
        ->load();
```

The problem is addAttributeTofilter() is not working, it shows me all items in that table instead of simple products. What did I do wrong?

Comment: try `addFieldToFilter` instead of `addAttributeToFilter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code , it will return you all simple product from that order

```
$orderItems = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('order_id',$orderId)
    ->addFieldToFilter('product_type', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);
```

Comment: this code works.... what did I do wrong? so we have to use sales/order_item instead of sales/order? what's the different?

Comment: The collection was already loaded in your code

Comment: $order->getItemsCollection() returned loaded collection and filtering was not possible on the loaded collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
$orderItems = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $orderId)
        ->addFieldToFilter('product_type', 'simple')
        ->load();
```

Comment: just tried it. I get the same result as if I used addAttributeToFilter

Comment: Can you paste the following output: foreach($orderItems as $item){echo $item->getProductType();}

Comment: There is no "simple" in the output?

Comment: sorry, the output is. "grouped","simple","configurable". this is what my problem is, it simply ignore the addAttributeToFilter or addFieldToFilter.

Comment: Try the edited answer

Comment: I just saw your edited code. This one is also working. Thanks